# Why would this code complain about "the arity of the generic type definition"?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, arity

I've got a generic type:

```
class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>>
```

And a factory method that will (should) create an instance of this class for a given dictionary type.

```
    private static IEqualityComparer<T> CreateDictionaryComparer<T>()
    {
        Type def = typeof(DictionaryComparer<,>);
        Debug.Assert(typeof(T).IsGenericType);
        Debug.Assert(typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().Length == 2);

        Type t = def.MakeGenericType(typeof(T).GetGenericArguments());

        return (IEqualityComparer<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
```

Stripping away all of the extraneous stuff - even this code throws the same exception.

```
private static object CreateDictionaryComparer()
{
    Type def = typeof(DictionaryComparer<,>);

    Type t = def.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(String), typeof(object) });

    return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
}
```

The Asserts pass so I know that `T` is generic and has two generic arguments. The line with `MakeGenericType` however excepts with:

> The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
>
> Parameter name: instantiation

I've done this sort of thing in the past and for the life of me can't figure out why this isn't working in this case. (plus I had to Google [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity)).

Comment: What are you passing as `T` to `CreateDictionaryComparer`? I've tried passing `CreateDictionaryComparer<IDictionary<string, string>>()` and this works fine for me (using Mono C# compiler version 1.9.1.0).

Comment: I had DictionaryComparer as an inner class to one that is itself generic. Think that was hosing up the works.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you provide the full (failing) sample so I can try it on my compiler?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had `DictionaryComparer` declared as an inner class. I can only assume that `MakeGenericType` wanted to make a `Query<T>.DictionaryComparer<string,object>` and was not provided `T`.

Failing code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var q = new Query<int>();
        q.CreateError();
    }
}

public class Query<TSource>
{
    public Query()
    {    
    }

    public object CreateError()
    {
        Type def = typeof(DictionaryComparer<,>);

        Type t = def.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(String), typeof(object) });

        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }

    class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>>
    {
        public DictionaryComparer()
        {
        }

        public bool Equals(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> x, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> y)
        {
            if (x.Count != y.Count)
                return false;

            return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> obj)
        {
            int hash = 0;
            unchecked
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in obj)
                {
                    int key = pair.Key.GetHashCode();
                    int value = pair.Value != null ? pair.Value.GetHashCode() : 0;
                    hash ^= key ^ value;
                }
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you provide the full (failing) sample so I can try it on my compiler?

Comment: Lemme see if I can strip unrelated stuff out to a compilable example

Comment: Thanks! Moving `DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue>` outside the generic container class `Query<TSource>` fixes the issue. I experimented and you can nest `DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue>`, just not inside another generic class. Also wanted to make sure my compiler and runtime environment were behaving the same as yours.

Comment: Mine is vs.net 2010 and .net 4.

Comment: As a further experiment providing three types new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(String), typeof(object) } also works, satisfying the need to make a concrete type for the containing class (though removing the inner class is the better solution)

Comment: Good to know. I believe `gmcs` 1.9.x is roughly equivalent to the Microsoft C# 3.0 compiler.

Comment: Thank you! This answer made my day as I was racking my brain trying to figure this one out

Answer (score 1):

CLR creates an internal data structure for each and every type in use by an application.These data structures are called type objects. A type with generic type parameters is called an open type, and the **CLR does not allow any instance of an open type to be constructed** (similar to how the CLR prevents an instance of an interface type from being constructed).

Change

```
Type t = def.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(String), typeof(object) });
```

on the

```
Type t = def.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(TSource), typeof(String), typeof(object) });
```